# A heart that never beats

Tags: riddle, word

What has a heart that never beats

I am the center

But has no blood

And it can rhyme with a homophone

I can move but slower than a sloth

What am I?

*Just another fast and simple riddle*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> Romaine (lettuce)

What has a heart that never beats
I am the center

> Romaine hearts

But has no blood

> Nope

And it can rhyme with a homophone

> Pain/Pane  Plane/Plain

I can move but slower than a sloth

> Lettuce grows slowly, can move slowly with the wind

Another thought

> Thought the same thing about hearts of palm and artichokes, but didn't have luck with the homophone

Comment: Correct! I never make hard ones ;)

Comment: @Duck but you still make pretty good ones, like this one, especially with the contrasting irony!  DVL13 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :P

Comment: On your "another thought": cnyz/onyz/obzo.

Answer (score 7):

Are you the

> Sun

What has a heart that never beats

> It has a core.

I am the center

> Of the solar system.

But has no blood

> Nope.

And it can rhyme with a homophone

> Sun Son

It can move but slower than a sloth

> It the solar system is revolving around the galaxy's center so it is moving slowly.

What am I

Comment: Hint- it is on Earth

Comment: Hahaha, well, that will narrow down the search from all of the other stars in the universe :)

Comment: You can hold the object, too. Again not the sun :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> Card?

What has a heart that never beats
I am the center

> Hearts are a suit of cards

But has no blood

> nope.

I know what you are thinking but it is not true

> I am not sure, but people guess what card sometimes.

And it can rhyme with a homophone

> Card -> yard(lot) or yard(yard, feet, meters).

Comment: Sorry, but it's not right. I will try to clarify some things

Comment: Now you can try again

Comment: Okay, will do @duck

Comment: Sure, I just got reminded of this when I went somewhere. Yes that was a hint +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> city?

because

> a city's heart can mean downtown. Also, 'city' rhymes with 'be'/'bee' which I think is a homophone.

Comment: Sorry, but no. +1 though